# pointing to a subfolder from a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

My main site `www.mysite.com` is using drupal

I would like to create a WP blog at `blog.mysite.com`  (I know I can create a blogging platform using drupal but don't wanna do that, WP is best for blogging it simply rocks)

I'm quite new to .htaccess and was wondering if there's a way to get 
`www.mysite.com/blog` pointing to `blog.mysite.com`  (since `mysite.com/blog` is better for SEO)
(but not redirecting there, it just has to load from there, so visitor sees `mysite.com/blog` in their browser)

Comment: I don'i think that `mysite.com/blog` is better than `blog.mysite.com` for SEO since content quality is now became the priority. Myblog lives as a subdomain under `wordpress.com`. It is now the [*1st rank*](https://www.google.com/search?q=hyip%20blog) google on the top of others who use their main domains.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mod_proxy enabled, you can use the `[P]` flag to internally proxy **www.mysite.com/blog** requests to **blog.mysite.com**. In the htaccess file for **www.mysite.com**'s document root (above any drupal related rules):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ http://blog.mysite.com/$1 [L,P]
```

If you don't have mod_proxy, you may need to setup WP somewhere in the same document root as your drupal site (like in `/blog/`) and get wordpress to work in a subdirectory. I've had mixed results in getting that to work with another CMS so not sure how much help I can give you there.

gvanto:
Thanks. I don't have mod_proxy but I think it may cause issues having it under a subdomain and accessing in this fashion (e.g. what will all the internal links be pointing to?). The 2nd option of having it in a subfolder is probably best: http://drupal.org/node/877828